# MYSQL PHP Where query error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This line: `$quey1="select * from clients WHERE USER == $current_user->user_login;";`

It returns an unknown error. There must be a simple syntax error in my code but I cannot seem to figure it out. BTW `$current_user->user_login;` returns a user, like `admin` for example.

Any idea what is wrong here? I'm realy new to this (first time ever touching php and mysql)

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$quey1 = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE USER = '" . $current_user->user_login . "'"
```

---

You should look after these also:

- escaping
- prepared statements
- PDO

Comment: thanks :). this works great! Could you explain what the "." are for? what do they mean?

Comment: They mean string concratenation but the main problem was the missing single qoutes and the wrong operator (==).

Answer (score 2):

PHP variables can be used in SQL queries (provided double quotes are used as single quotes are treated as string literals (so `$something` is literally interpreted as `$something`, not a variable), their values are simply substituted at the time of the query, however variable manipulatin is not possible. Your best bet is to replace it with a single variable. Also the semicolon in the query is not needed, as it is interpreted as a column. The `==` can be replaced with just `=` as you are extracting data, not setting data:

```
$user = $current_user->user_login;
$quey1 = "select * from clients WHERE USER == $user";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a double equals operator in MySQL. And any string comparison needs quotes.

```
$quey1 = "select * from clients WHERE USER = '{$current_user->user_login}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `current_user->user_login` in quotes.  Otherwise MySQL thinks that it's a column.  The error is that there is no column called "admin."